# Three.js axis directions

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I draw vectors in three.js , I realized that the axis are kinda mixed up. I can deal with Y being the vertical axis, but both X and Z are "mirrored" and I can see the objects like I want, only If I look upside-down. 
How do I fix that?
I can rotate the camera representation/objects, but I don't think it will work. I need a general World X Y Z representation change.

The whole program uses:

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script src="getparam.js"></script>    
<script src="dat.gui.js"></script>
<script src="three.js"></script>
<script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="Stats.js"></script>
<script src="Program.js"></script>
```

so I am not sure where the code is.

This is the wrong JS representation:
[image: This is the wrong JS representation]
This is how it should be
[image: This is how it should be]

Comment: without code how can we test your application?

Comment: I don't know how to upload the folder with all the sources.

Comment: you should reproduce your problem with minimal code example.there is no need to upload all the source code.you can use jsfiddle,codepen..etc to add additional codes.i guess camera position is wrong.

Comment: http://babameca.comlu.com/?run=cuki.js Here it is

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear exactly what behaviour you're after, but try specifying a different up vector for the camera.  E.g.:

```
camera.up(0, 0, 1);
```

...assuming **camera** contains the camera you're using for rendering, and you want Z to be "up".  To see how this behaves [here's a trivial jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tv2ddoyv/):

```
var scene, camera, cube, light;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  var height = 500,
    width = 500;
  var bg = '#000000';

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper(50);
  scene.add(axisHelper);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, height / width, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(20, 20, 20);
  //camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
  camera.lookAt(axisHelper.position);
  scene.add(camera);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setClearColor(bg);
  renderer.setSize(width, height);

  var d = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(d);
  d.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  c.style.width = width + 'px';
  c.style.height = height + 'px'
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

This renders an AxisHelper, showing the orientation of the axes (x is red, y is green, z is blue).  Uncomment the line that sets the camera's up vector and re-run it to see the difference.